# Enable Scroll for particular Component

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have disabled scroll through my project by specifying a code in `style.scss`. Now I need to enable scroll for a particular component's template. But I couldn't do it.

**style.scss**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

The above is to disable the scroll through the project.

**abc.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 scroll">
    <div class="card">
</div>
```

**abc.scss**

```
.scroll {
    max-height: 100px!important;
    overflow-y: auto!important;
}
```

I am not seeing any scroll for the above (`abc.html & abc.scss`) code. Please help me out

Comment: `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` will not work with firefox browser. Check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `::-webkit-scrollbar` element to `display: none`. You would need to display it again:

```
.scroll {
    max-height: 100px!important;
    overflow-y: auto!important;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: initial;
    }
}
```